# Are there any commands that cannot be redefined?

Tags: errors, undefined, definition

i.e. Can I redefine `\def`, or `\renewcommand`? Is there a definitive list?

Comment: Depends what you consider as a command (within TeX, `a` is considered a command, for example), but in normal TeX all control sequences `\whatever` can be redefined.  Recent ConTeXt has some goodies to prevent that

Comment: you can test yourself `\def\def{zzzz} \def`   works, it breaks almost everything else but that is a different issue

Comment: There are more than enough commands that *should* not be redefined, at least not without exhaustive tests and thoughts. This list includes the primitives.

Comment: Basically TeX is a macro language and you can (re)define any macro. There are many that you should not redefine. Only redefine something if you know what it does and how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed the so called "frozen `\relax`" that TeX inserts on unfinished conditionals (see [this answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169229/117050)).

You can use this insertion to define a macro to expand to this special `\relax` by using:

```
\edef\x{\ifnum1=1\fi}
```

Since TeX will insert `\relax` this is equivalent to

```
\edef\x{\ifnum1=1\relax\fi}
```

And since `\edef` will expand the definition as far as possible the `\ifnum1=1` will be true and that and `\fi` removed due to expansion.

Now `\x` will expand to `\relax`, but this `\relax` token will not be redefinable (well, frozen). So the following throws an `\inaccessible` error on the second line:

```
\edef\x{\ifnum1=1\fi}
\expandafter\def\x{}
```

The complete error message will be

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.2 \expandafter\def\x
                      {}
```

Comment: On the other hand, if you say `\expandafter\let\expandafter\frozenrelax\x`, the test `\ifx\frozenrelax\relax` will return true and `\frozenrelax` can be redefined.

Comment: @egreg Yes, `\let` unfreezes it. Also `\expandafter\ifx\x\relax` will be true as well.